How to improve compile time for LLVM MCJit
I need advice to improve LLVM MCJit compile time.
I'm using llvmlite (Python bindings to LLVM) to implement arithmetic circuits. An arithmetic circuit is coded as a single module with a single function. The function takes three arrays (input, temp, and output). The function body loads from the arrays, performs arithmetic operations, and stores to the arrays. The function may perform many arithmetic operations (e.g. millions).
Each compiled function executes very quickly - great! However compiling take a long time  (i.e., mcjit compiler finalize_object method). For example, compiling 11k operations takes 5 seconds, 34k ops takes 22s. This seems ridiculously long for such a simple structure.
Here's a snippet of the LLVM code (showing 5 arithmetic operations with 3 stores).
; ModuleID = ""
target triple = "unknown-unknown-unknown"
target datalayout = ""

define void @"main"(double* %".1", double* %".2", double* %".3")
{
entry:
  %".5" = getelementptr double, double* %".1", i32 4
  %".6" = load double, double* %".5"
  %".7" = getelementptr double, double* %".1", i32 8
  %".8" = load double, double* %".7"
  %".9" = fmul double %".6", %".8"
  %".10" = fmul double %".9", 0x3fe6666666666666
  %".11" = getelementptr double, double* %".2", i32 0
  store double %".10", double* %".11"
  
  %".13" = getelementptr double, double* %".1", i32 4
  %".14" = load double, double* %".13"
  %".15" = getelementptr double, double* %".1", i32 9
  %".16" = load double, double* %".15"
  %".17" = fmul double %".14", %".16"
  %".18" = fmul double %".17", 0x3fd3333333333333
  %".19" = getelementptr double, double* %".2", i32 1
  store double %".18", double* %".19"
  
  %".21" = getelementptr double, double* %".2", i32 0
  %".22" = load double, double* %".21"
  %".23" = getelementptr double, double* %".2", i32 1
  %".24" = load double, double* %".23"
  %".25" = fadd double %".22", %".24"
  %".26" = getelementptr double, double* %".2", i32 2
  store double %".25", double* %".26"
  
  ; and so on ...
  
  ret void
}

At compile time, memory utilisation is 30% so not an issue. One CPU is at 100%. I have looked for ways to disable JIT optimisations but can't see anything. Also tried not using the "temp" array and instead let MCJit use the stack. The stack-based approach is a lot better but still far from effective (and allocates a lot of stack memory).
Any advice?

I discovered how to switch off optimisation. With llvmlite use: target = llvm.Target.from_default_triple().create_target_machine(opt=0), then llvm.create_mcjit_compiler(llvm_module, target). This can speed up compilation by an order of magnitude. Still very slow compilation for large functions.
I also tried breaking the function up into sub-functions, one per sequence that concludes with a store instruction.  Sub-functions just made compilation and execution times slower. Tried with 'alwaysinline' and 'noinline' attribute - no real difference.
